# Switching on and off Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I switch on and off bluetooth directly without needing to have a pop up asking user consent. 
I tried btAdapter.enable() but this did not work for me.

Comment: Did you added permission to manifest file. {<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />}

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, It required android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you'd need to add it to the permissions xml (AndroidManifest.xml) file to not have user intervention.

http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/103281.aspx

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, It required android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Answer (score 1):

```
 String status;
   if (bluetooth.isEnabled()) {
    String mydeviceaddress = bluetooth.getAddress();
    String mydevicename = bluetooth.getName();
     status = mydevicename + ” : ” + mydeviceaddress;
           }
          else
                  {
                         status = “Bluetooth is not Enabled.”;
                  }

      Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Do on or off now ur wish :)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, It required android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    //do some thing here
  }else{
    //do some thing here
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I figured it out, It required android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission